# Only UNLocationNotificationTrigger isn't triggered

Tags: ios, objective-c, unusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to get a notification when a user enters a region, but I'm not receiving any location notifications.

I'm just using the sample code provided on Apple's documentation page for `UNLocationNotificationTrigger`. The problem is, the code works perfectly for all other triggers except for this. My app has location permissions - I am easily able to get a location from the `CLLocationManager`. I even modified my code to also register a delegate for the locationManager, and the `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` work flawlessly, but the location notification just doesn't fire.

This is the code that registers the location notification:

```c
CLLocationCoordinate2D point = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.335400, -122.009201);

CLCircularRegion* region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:point
        radius:2000.0 identifier:@"Headquarters"];
region.notifyOnEntry = YES;
region.notifyOnExit = NO;

UNLocationNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNLocationNotificationTrigger
        triggerWithRegion:region repeats:YES];
UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest 
        requestWithIdentifier:[details.id stringValue] content:content trigger:trigger];
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to Add Notification Request");
    }
}];
```

When I retrieve pending notifications, it even shows:

```
<UNNotificationRequest: 0x6000024525b0; identifier: 20, content: <UNNotificationContent: 0x60000113fdc0; title: <redacted>, subtitle: (null), body: <redacted>, summaryArgument: , summaryArgumentCount: 0, categoryIdentifier: location, launchImageName: , threadIdentifier: , attachments: (
), badge: (null), sound: <UNNotificationSound: 0x60000010d570>, realert: 0, trigger: <UNLocationNotificationTrigger: 0x600002a4e980; repeats: YES, region: CLCircularRegion (identifier:'Headquarters', center:<+37.33540000,-122.00920100>, radius:2000.00m)>>
```

I use iOS 13.2 Simulator, and when I register the locationManager delegate, I can get that same region to trigger enter and exit events just fine, but the notification just never fires. Any ideas where I might be doing things wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is running in the foreground. But all other notifications fire whether or not my app is running
Edit: Just to clarify, I'm talking about `UNUserNotification`s, and in my code I am forcing them to display even in foreground.

Comment: As per Sam's answer and the linked blog post, it should work just fine in the simulator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, never mind, apparently it was the Simulator acting up for 2 days. Today, with absolutely no code change, it is working perfectly.

Comment: This jibes with my experience. An iOS project that was triggering notifications just stopped working with the same project and same code. Haven't yet been able to get it restarted.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is set up as it should, you should be able to see it when triggering a location change from the simulator's debug menu.

Highlight the simulator's window and from the *Debug* menu, select *Location > Custom Location* and enter the coordinates for the region which should trigger the notification.

[image]

You can find more information in the following article - https://medium.com/@jonathan2457/location-triggered-notifications-on-ios-24033919fb9a

Comment: Yes, that's how I've been changing my location - doesn't work. When I register a locationManager delegate and create a geofence the "traditional" way, it does, however, so the issue seems to be in the notification center.

Comment: I see. When the notification is being triggered, is the device's location set to be out of the triggering region?

Comment: Yes. I have myself be at some random location in Europe when I register the notification, and then I set my location to Apple Headquarters. The geofence from locationManager triggers the didEnterRegion function, but the notification does not display. Tried setting it while inside and exiting and re-entering: again, the locationManager delegate registers both events, but notification doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue. I deleted the app from the simulator, quit the simulator, cleaned the build folder in Xcode (Shift+Command+K)and re-ran the app and it worked after that.